# Why does Chrome show duplicate HTTP requests when using the angular service-worker?

Tags: angular, google-chrome, service-worker, angular-service-worker

When chrome makes HTTP requests with the angular service-worker enabled, I see something like this in the Chrome network tab:

[image]

- Why does the chrome network tab show two requests for each request made, one fetch, one xhr? (I only see one request on the server)
- Why is there no response data for the fetch request?
- Is the duration and size of each request accurate?

I'm following the [official service-worker guide](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started) and I'm on the latest Angular 9.

In firefox I do not see the duplicate requests:
[image: http://localhost:8080/]

Chrome version: 81.0.4044.129

Firefox version: 76.0

Answer (score 5):

Service worker is handling this request, it's like proxy. The original request is dismissed. This is happening because SW is caching responses (like images, styles or routing) for better performance - instead of downloading resources all the time from server (but this can be changed in [`Service worker configuration`](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-config)), SW is serving them from browser cache. It's working even if user is offline - that's why routing is working, because service worker is serving html from cache and it's possible to reach the site

Comment: you are talking about fetch request or xhr one?